# Como passar uma função de referencia implementada diretamente no argumento?

Tags: c++

Como posso fazer isso em C++ ?

```
void run(Function){
//Faça algo
Function(); //Executar funcao do argumento
}


int main(){

//Criar e passar como parametro
run({
int a = 5;
int b = 10;
cout<< a+b << endl;
})

}
```

Aproveitando o topico, e se eu quisesse que ela retornasse um 'int' ou recebesse dois 'int' ?

Answer (score 0):

Acabei encontrando a solução e envolve função anônima e passagem de função por parâmetro.

Para passagem da função por parametro:

```
  <tipo Retorno> (*<nomeFuncao>)(<argumentos>)
//Exemplo
void (*myFunc)();
```

Criar função anônima:

```
[<capture>] (<argumentos>) -> <tipo Retorno> { <corpo> } 

Exemplo:
    [](int a) -> int {
    int a = 5;
    return a; 
    }
```

Juntando os dois fica:

```
void run(void (*myFunc)()){
    myFunc();
}

int main()
{
    run([]() -> void {
        cout<<"LIDO"<<endl;
    });
    
//Caso não tenha argumentos e retorno, pode-se simplificar.
    run([]{
        int a=5;
        int b=58;
        
        cout<<a+b<<endl;
    });

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Provavelmente _"uma solução"_ seria melhor descrição que _"a solução"_. Há muitas maneiras de fazer isso em C++.